# SQL how to expand table to more filed base on one filed's value

Tags: sql

SQL how to expand table to more filed base on one filed's value

Such as,
I have something like this:

```
ID   Name Age  YearQuarter Points
1    Tom   13   20131      100
1    Tom   13   20132      99
3    May   13   20133       98
```

I need

```
ID   Name Age   Points20131  Points20132  Points20133
1    Tom   13   100           99           NA
3    May   13   NA            NA           98
```

I have tryied something like

```
SELECT ID, Name,Age, Points as 'Points20131', 'NA' as 'Points20132', 'NA' as 'Point20133'
FROM table where YearQuarter = 20131
UNION
SELECT ID, Name,Age, 'NA' as 'Points20131', Points  as 'Points20132', 'NA' as 'Point20133'
FROM table where YearQuarter = 20132
UNION
SELECT ID, Name,Age, 'NA' as 'Points20131',  'NA'  as 'Points20132', Points as 'Point20133'
FROM table where YearQuarter = 20133
```

But this generates 2 Tom's records.
such as

```
ID   Name Age   Points20131  Points20132  Points20133
1    Tom   13   100           NA           NA
2    Tom   13   NA            99           NA
3    May   13   NA            NA           98
```

How to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you are trying to do.  It sounds like you want to add a column, rather than use a SELECT. Are you using MySQL, or something else?  Take a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).  Also, you may want to store this in a separate table, with fields for player id, the year, the month, and the score; it will make things easier rather than adding a field every month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try CASE WHEN like

```
SELECT MIN(tt.ID) as ID, 
       tt.Name,
       tt.Age, 
       ISNULL(CAST(SUM(Points20131) as varchar(10)),'NA') as 'Points20131',
       ISNULL(CAST(SUM(Points20132) as varchar(10)),'NA') as 'Points20132',
       ISNULL(CAST(SUM(Points20133) as varchar(10)),'NA') as 'Points20133'
FROM
(
   SELECT ID, 
          Name,
          Age, 
          CASE WHEN YearQuarter = '20131' THEN Points ELSE NULL END as 'Points20131', 
          CASE WHEN YearQuarter = '20132' THEN Points ELSE NULL END as 'Points20132', 
          CASE WHEN YearQuarter = '20133' THEN Points ELSE NULL END as 'Points20133' 
   FROM Test
) tt
GROUP BY tt.NAME, tt.Age
ORDER BY MIN(tt.ID)
```

SQL Fiddle Demo : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49fd0/19

Comment: thanks. but this is has some wrongness. for example,  my purpose result of Tom has one record. but your method will generate 2 records, how to fix that?

Comment: In that case you need to add grouping like I have done. Please check my updated answer